How do I point Cassandra to alternative Java path?
I am using Debian 12 server that comes with JDK 17. I have installed openJDK 11 as well on the server. Cassandra version is 4.0.10.
I want to point Cassandra to JDK 11, while leaving the default Java version for the system at JDK 17, but I am unable to do so.
Using update-alternatives, if I set JDK11 as the preferred manual option, Cassandra starts up just fine.
However when I set JAVA_HOME to the JDK 11 path in the cassandra sh files and set the java alternative to JDK 17, Cassandra start fails with:
FATAL: Cassandra is unable to access required classes. This usually means it has been run without the aid of the standard startup scripts or the scripts have been edited. If this was intentional, and you are attempting to use Java 11+ you may need to add the --add-exports and --add-opens jvm options from either jvm11-server.options or jvm11-client.options
Detailed steps:
Initial state of the system:
Default Java is JDK 11:
update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status

  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1711      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1711      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

JAVA_HOME is commented out in Cassandra conf files.
Cassandra is up and running.
Steps done to point Cassandra to JDK 11:

nodetool drain

My CASSANDRA_HOME is /usr/local/cassandra/apache-cassandra-4.0.10/ . Edited the following files to set JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64:


/usr/local/cassandra/apache-cassandra-4.0.10/local-cassandra.in.sh
/usr/local/cassandra/apache-cassandra-4.0.10//bin/cassandra.in.sh
/usr/local/cassandra/apache-cassandra-4.0.10//tools/bin/cassandra.in.sh

Set java alternative to Java 17:

update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status

  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1711      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1711      manual mode
Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode

which java
/usr/bin/java

java --version
openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+7-Debian-1deb12u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+7-Debian-1deb12u1, mixed mode, sharing)


restart cassandra - fails with this message in the log:

ERROR [main] 2024-04-04 03:31:04,973 FileUtils.java:106 - FATAL: Cassandra is unable to access required classes. This usually means it has been run without the aid of the standard startup scripts or the scripts have been edited. If this was intentional, and you are attempting to use Java 11+ you may need to add the --add-exports and --add-opens jvm options from either jvm11-server.options or jvm11-client.options

Restored java alternative to JDK 11 and restart cassandra was successful.

Not sure how to fix this. Where should I add the jvm options (not sure if that will solve the issue at all). Am I missing any steps? Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

I have done this with JEnv, and I highly recommend it. It allows you to specify a version of Java for a specific directory. Definitely makes it easier to run different versions of Cassandra with specific versions of Java.
https://www.jenv.be/
** Edit **

Meanwhile, any idea why Cassandra is not able to pick up JDK11 in spite of JAVA_HOME being set in the conf files?

Have a look in bin/cassandra.in.sh. If something isn't being read properly from the JAVA_HOME, it'll be overridden by the JDK in the PATH var.
» grep JAVA_HOME cassandra.in.sh

# JAVA_HOME can optionally be set here
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk6
# Use JAVA_HOME if set, otherwise look for java in PATH
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
    for java in "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/amd64/java "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java; do
    echo Unable to find java executable. Check JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables. >&2


Thank you @Aaron for the quick response. Installing new tool/code on production servers is a bit of a challenge for us, I will try and pursue the possibility of using jenv. Meanwhile, any idea why Cassandra is not able to pick up JDK11 in spite of JAVA_HOME being set in the conf files?

@RPS edit made. TL;DR; check how JAVA_HOME is handled in the bin/cassandra.in.sh file.
